# FinancialData don't give the right result

Tags: plotting, curated-data, time-series

Could you perhaps explain me the following behaviour?
My code is:

```
sp500 = FinancialData["^SPX", {2007, 1, 1}, Method -> "Legacy"]
```

This gives me a list that ends with yesterday's value (4,509.37 at 2021-08-27).

But without "Method->Legacy" it shows the last value somewhere in the middle of 2020.

In addition, when I run this:

```
DateListPlot[{zlato, sp500}, PlotLegends -> {"gold", "SP500"}]
```

I get a chart where you can see the gold price is up-to-date, but SP500 is not.

[image]

Any idea, why would that be?

Thanks,

Jiri

P.S. zlato is gold, is defined as

```
zlato = FinancialData["XAU/USD", {2007, 1, 1}, Method -> "Legacy"]
```

With PlotRange limited to 2020-2021, the Plot looks like this:
[image]

Comment: What is zlato? You forgot to include its definition. `DateListPlot[sp500]` is up to date for me in v12.3.1.  Are you sure you aren't  just missing a PlotRange option in the DateListPlot ?

Comment: zlato is `zlato = FinancialData["XAU/USD", {2007, 1, 1}, Method -> "Legacy"]`

Comment: PlotRange doesn't change anything with `DateListPlot[{zlato, sp500}, PlotLegends -> {"gold", "SP500"}, 
 PlotRange -> {{{2020}, {2021}}, Automatic}]` you get a more detailed plot obviously, but still with missing data for SP500.

Comment: I think the issue is the different dimension of the two time series - the gold has got more trading dates (entries) than there are trading dates of SP500. Would you agree?

Comment: Try adding the `PlotRange -> All` option to each `DateListPlot`.

Answer (score 2):

To make the plot synchoronized I had to do TimeSeriesResample so that both time-series had the same "DatePath". Then the DateListPlot works without problem.